# Deactivate Microsoft Dynamics 2013 Workflow from the javascript of a web resource

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, xrm, xrmservicetoolkit

I have a web resource in Microsoft Dynamics 2013 with an event in javascript where I would like to duplicate the same functionality of deactivating a workflow as the "Deactivate" button on the edit workflow page in CRM.

I'm using the XrmServiceToolkit, and I was hoping that I would be able to "SetSate" of the workflow with the Soap call provided within the toolkit. 
Like this...

```
XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.SetState(myWorflowNameHere, myWorflowIdHere, 1, 2);
```

Or even better ;)

```
XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.InactivateWorkflow(myWorkflowId);
```

There doesn't appear to be anything else available for what I'm trying to do.

My main goal of this exercise is to be able to edit a workflow from the javascript.  To edit the workflow, it needs to be inactivated.  I can get any data from the Workflow that I need to make this happen.

Any help regarding updating the ACTIVE workflow, or INACTIVATING the workflow from javascript is appreciated.

Rules:
It HAS to be done in the javascript of the web resource.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the id, you should be able to call

```
XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.SetState("workflow", workflowId, 0, 1); //StateCode: 0 = Draft, StatusCode: 1 = Draft
```

Comment: Thanks, I was so close, but so very far away.